# Django can't find template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I know many people have asked, this question, but despite hardcoding the path to my template directory I can't seem to get Django to find my template.

Here is settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "/Users/full/path/to/marketing_site/templates",
)
```

This is the views.py file:

```
def static (request, feature_page):

# this will get the appropriate feature page template.
template = loader.get_template('features/pricing.html')
c = RequestContext(request,{
})
return HttpResponse(template.render(c))
```

Inside the main folder is the templates folder and the app folder.  I use to put the apps in the same folder as settings.py but it appears django 1.4 has changed the default file structure.

My error is:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /features/pricing 

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/feature_pricing.html (File does not exist)
```

Update:
My logs for the webpage list the TEMPLATE_DIRS as ().

If I put a print statement on the settings.py page for the TEMPLATE_DIRS I get a printout of the TEMPLATE_DIRS appropriately... so somehow the TEMPLATE_DIRS isn't being used (from what it looks like)

Comment: I am assuming you are using windows?

Comment: You do have your project's path added to python sys path?

Comment: No I am using OS X... I don't have the project path added to python sys path, how would I do this?

Comment: I should mention I am using the runserver test parameter and not apache or nginx to load the webpage

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had added in an extra TEMPLATE_DIR in the settings.py

:(

Comment: Argh! Just found out my problem was the same. It had stopped work for a good couple of days... :D

Answer (score 5):

it's better to set up relative paths for your path variables. You can set it up like so:

```
import os

PATH_PROJECT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

...

...

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PATH_PROJECT + '/templates/'
)
```

Also assuming you are using windows you may want to try:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
"C:/Users/full/path/to/marketing_site/templates",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting `/Users/full/path/to/marketing_site/templates` does not contain a `features` directory, or `/Users/full/path/to/marketing_site/templates/features` does not contain a `pricing.html` file.

Based on your comment, it looks like you're calling `loader.get_template('feature_pricing.‌​html')`, instead of using `'feature/pricing.html'`.

EDIT: I didn't notice this before:

> Inside the main folder is the templates folder and the app folder. I use to put the apps in the same folder as settings.py but it appears django 1.4 has changed the default file structure.

That could be causing the issue. Change the directory structure to match the 1.4 Django conventions. You might just recreate the project, copy the relevant settings over into the newly create settings.py, and copy all the files.

Comment: directory and permissions are ok... the route exists... here is more to the error code:                                                    Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/feature_pricing.html (File does not exist)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding project paths to django.wsgi

```
import os
import sys

paths = ('path/to/project/',
        'path/to/more /included/directories/',
    )

for path in paths:
    if path not in sys.path:
       sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: I am using right now the runserver testing mechanism... would this make a difference?